# How do you save variable state in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, persistence

I'm completely new to Actionscript and I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to save variable state in Flash. I figure I could use XML but is there a way to store it in the Flash file itself? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, look up [Shared Objects](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05B_Security_15.html). It's what they are for, either locally or remotely.